# How do I parse out Author information using a Regex in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following text:

```
BATTLE HYMN OF THE TIGER MOTHER, by Amy Chua. (Penguin 
Press, $25.95.) A Chinese-American mother makes a case for strict 
and demanding parenting
```

I'd like to use a regex to parse out:

```
Title
Author
Publisher
MSRP (Retail Price)
Description
```

How do I write a regex to do this in C#?

Comment: can you provide sample input and output of what you would like the regex to match on? do you need to capture anything?

Comment: `(?<MATCH>This makes no sense\.)` should work.

Comment: You want a regular expression *that will do what?* Do you wish to capture the title, author, publisher, price, and synopsis as separate fields? Then say so, please.

Comment: You should add more clarification to your question. Are you wanting to use regex to validate a string like this? You would be better off validating the individual components that make up this string (i.e. ensure that a user provides a publisher, title and author instead of leaving any blank.)

Comment: I think the OP wants to match book titles like that, not necessarily, for example, the price of the book.

Comment: @all sorry about that....i have updated my q

Comment: @S..: Are the fields *always* going to be distinguishable by the following criteria? 1. Comma ending the title; no commas present in titles. 2. Author name always ended by period, preceded by the word "by" 3. Publisher and price always in parenthesis, separated by comma. No commas present in publisher names. If these rules apply, you should be able to devise a substring search or regex match.

Comment: @S..: could you show us what you've got so far?  That would be helpful as the structure of the class you're trying to map to and what regex you've got so far is not really clear.

Comment: @JYelton..........no its not the same.........in some cases it has comma in the titles it doest not have description and price in some case....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just saw answers were allowed again. This is my recommended regex:

```
^(?<title>[\w\s]*), by (?<author>[\w\s]*)\. \((?<publisher>[\w\s]*), (?<msrp>.*)\.\) (?<description>.*)$
```

It will give you a named capture for the fields above and can be used in C# like this:

```
private void Main()
    {
        string input = "BATTLE HYMN OF THE TIGER MOTHER, by Amy Chua. (Penguin Press, $25.95.) A Chinese-American mother makes a case for strict and demanding parenting";

        string pattern = @"^(?<title>[\w\s]*), by (?<author>[\w\s]*)\. \((?<publisher>[\w\s]*), (?<msrp>.*)\.\) (?<description>.*)$";

        MatchCollection myMatchCollection = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

        foreach (Match myMatch in myMatchCollection)
        {
            var title = myMatch.Groups["title"];
            var author = myMatch.Groups["author"];
            var publisher = myMatch.Groups["publisher"];
            var msrp = myMatch.Groups["msrp"];
            var description = myMatch.Groups["description"];
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you.....this helped me for the pattern i mentioned in my q....i will try for other patterns

Comment: this is working fine but failed with this string pattern ** TICK TOCK, by James Patterson and Michael Ledwidge. (Little,  Brown, $27.99.) The New York detective Michael Bennett enlists  the help of a former colleague to solve a rash of horrifying crimes  that are throwing the city into chaos. **   as there is a comma in the publisher:(

Comment: I would modify this part: \((?<publisher>[\w\s]*), (?<msrp>.*)\.\) to this: \((?<publisher>[\w\s,]*), \$(?<msrp>.*)\.\)

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be simpler to:

- Split on "(" or ")"
- Split on "by" for the left part
- Split on ", " for the middle part
- right part is your description

Using the string.Split() method.

This all of course depends on how reliable the pattern is--as the above commenters mention.

Answer (score 0):

This does it:

```
^([ \w]+), by ([ \w]+). \(([ \w]+), ([$.\d]+)\) ([ \w-]+)$
```

You can add named groups to pull them out by name or just the matches by index. However this will most likely be incredibly brittle unless your source data is very strict.

I've also only done it for this one example, the description has a `-` in it, which is an example of a special character in the names, so you might want to make sure those are handled as you expect.